# How to get a given number by performing operations on a given list - Python

Tags: python

I have been trying to get an idea of how to solve this. If you have any idea on how to solve this, can you help out?
Doubt is,
If a list [3,4,9] is given and a number for example 87 is given, and the only operation allowed is multiplication, the number of steps doesn't matter.
After rough work, we can say that we should perform 3 operations in order to get the answer.

1. 3 x 3 = 9
2. 4 x 15 = 60
3. 9 x 2 = 18

---

After adding the values of the above operations, we get the value 87.
Another example,
If the list is [2,4,8] and the given value is 16, we perform a single operation

1. 2 x 2 = 4

---

So, 4+4+8=16. So, the number of steps required is 1.
I have tried to write a program, but it can only perform a single operation on the whole list at a time

```
a=int(input())
b=list(map(int,input().split()))
h=0
p=len(b) 
for i in range(2,100):
   d=b[0:p]
   c=[i*x for x in d]
   if(sum(c)==a):
       print(i)
       break
   if(sum(c)>a):
       p-=1
print("Not possible to obtain the sum with single operation")
```

The above code can only perform operations of single digits on the whole digits. Similarly, I can write 3 for loops if the list is of length 3. But, the length of the list varies. What should I do in such cases?
I want the code to display the minimum number of operations required to perform on the given list in order to obtain the given answer and also display the required operations if possible.
Thank you

Comment: I think you basically want to do a breadth-first-search on the decision tree of possible next operations. Once a branch finds your number, you stop. This would work if the possible multiplication factors are a finite set, but it sounds like they could be arbitrarily big. In that case, it's not obvious to me right now how to solve this. Can you be more explicit about your assumptions? Such as "Can there be negative numbers in the list? Or are they just positive integers?", "are the factors all positive integers? Is there a maximum allowed factor?" etc.

Comment: All the numbers should be positive. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the code to display minimum number of operations required to perform on the given list in order to obtain the give answer and also display he required operations if possible.

### Assumptions

- The target number is a positive integer
  (Non-positive integers can be handled as well, by multiplying everything by minus one. But not having to deal with that helps thinking clearly about it)
- The coefficients for the multiplications are non-negative integers
  (Negative integers would mean we need to multiply them with a negative number to reach the same effect. We could do that, I just did not want to think about this case)
- The numbers in the list are integers
  (Otherwise the problem would either be unsolvable, or always solvable in one operation)
- Choosing a list element only once counts also as multiplication operation `1*element`
  (That assumption could easily be removed)

### Approach

Given `target` and a `number_list`, we want to find a way to compute `target` by multiplying list elements with coefficients and summing them up. For some reason, I found it simpler to think about this in the opposite direction (but both should work, I think). That is, I subtract `coefficient * element` from `target` and end up with the same problem again, but with a smaller `target`. This is the essence of a recursive problem.

It could technically happen, that we subtract a big number from `target` and end up with something unsolvable, while subtracting a smaller number would result in something solvable. So we need to consider *all possible coefficients, for all possible list elements*.
Possible coefficients are coefficients that are greater than zero and small enough that `coefficient * element` is not greater than target.

If you think of all the possible paths to choose as a tree of decisions (where the edges are all the possible choices to make), we have two options to walk through that tree: Either depth-first (follow one path all the way down, then the next, and so on) or breadth-first. I chose the latter, because that allows us to stop a bit sooner: The first path to succeed will be pretty short.

In fact, I believe it will be even optimal in the number of operations, because any future options to consider will be branches in the tree that are at least the same length. However, I wrote the code a bit more defensively just in case this belief is not true. Instead of instantly aborting when I find one path that works, I continue to work through the queue but ignore all paths that are already longer than the currently best one.

To know which operations were done, I track the `history` as a list of tuples containing each list element and the coefficient that corresponds to it.

### Result

Run on your example with `number_list = [3, 4, 9]` and `target = 87`, I get:

```
Target 87 was reached using 1 multiplication operations.
history: [(3, 29)]
```

And we can check that `3*29` is indeed 87 and needed only a single operation. Note that this is better than your suggestion of three operations :D

### Code

*Written in python 3.8*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70721453/how-to-get-a-given-number-by-performing-operations-on-a-given-list-python?noredirect=1#comment125023761_70721453
from dataclasses import dataclass

def main():
    number_list = [3, 4, 9]
    target = 87

    result_state = solve( number_list, target )

    if result_state is None:
        print(f"That was not solvable!")
    else:
        print (f"Target {target} was reached using {result_state.n_ops_done} multiplication operations.")
        print (f"history: {result_state.history}")

@dataclass
class State:
    """
        Class to keep track of number of operations done in one 
        BFS path.
    """
    n_ops_done: int = 0
    current_target: int = 0
    # optional but nice for seeing which operations were taken:
    #   A list of the elements used.
    history : list = None

def solve( number_list, target ):
    """
        Finds the smallest number of multiplication operations required to 
        compute `target` as a sum of products c*el where el can be any list element
        of `number_list` and c has to be a positive integer.

        returns `None` if this is not possible with the given numbers,
        otherwise returns a `State` object.
    """
    # create a queue for Breath-First Search
    queue = [State(current_target = target, history = [])]

    best_state = None

    # while the queue is not empty, we work through items in it, one after
    # the other. In insertion order.
    # Extract from the start, add to the end.
    while queue:
        state = queue.pop(0)

        if state.current_target == 0:
            # found a path that works. Is it optimal?
            if (best_state is None) or (best_state.n_ops_done > state.n_ops_done):
                best_state = state

        if (best_state is not None) and (best_state.n_ops_done <= state.n_ops_done):
            # no need to proceed, it will not be optimal.
            continue

        for el in number_list:
            maximal_coefficient = state.current_target // el
            for coeff in range(maximal_coefficient, 0, -1):
                # create new state to add to queue.
                queue.append(State(
                        n_ops_done = state.n_ops_done + 1,
                        current_target = state.current_target - (coeff * el),
                        history = state.history.copy() + [(el, coeff)]
                    ))

    return best_state

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `itertools.product(range(1, target + 1), repeat=len(lst))` to create a list of all possible combinations of factors (e.g. `(1,1,1) (1,1,2)...`). Be careful with longer lists and high target numbers, as the list of factors can get very long, quickly.

```
import itertools

def get_factors(lst, target):
    factors = itertools.product(range(1, target + 1), repeat=len(lst))
    results = []

    for fac in factors:
        sum_ = sum(i*j for i, j in zip(lst, fac))
        if sum_ == target:
            results.append(fac)
    return results

lst = [3, 4, 9]
results = get_factors(lst, 87)
print(results)
```

This finds all possible solutions. As we can see, there are some that only require 2 steps:

```
[(1, 3, 8), (1, 12, 4), (2, 9, 5), (2, 18, 1), (3, 6, 6), (3, 15, 2), (4, 3, 7), (4, 12, 3), (5, 9, 4), (6, 6, 5), (6, 15, 1), (7, 3, 6), (7, 12, 2), (8, 9, 3), (9, 6, 4), (10, 3, 5), (10, 12, 1), (11, 9, 2), (12, 6, 3), (13, 3, 4), (14, 9, 1), (15, 6, 2), (16, 3, 3), (18, 6, 1), (19, 3, 2), (22, 3, 1)]
```

To find the minimum amount of steps, we have to find the result with the most "1"s:

```
ones = max(fac.count(1) for fac in results)
print("Steps required:", len(lst) - ones)
# Steps required: 2
```

This leaves a lot room for optimization. It calculates way more numbers than necessary.

Comment: Nice! That's a clean short example. +1. But I'm wondering now why your program says `Steps required: 2` for the same example that I get the solution to multiply the list element `3` with `29` and am done with just that one multiplication?

Comment: Ah, because you only consider factors starting at one.